# Why django doesn't save encrypted password?

Tags: python, django

I've using django 1.4. When creating a new user, it saves plain password. Is there a setting for it so when saving a user, the password is saved encrypted?

**EDIT**

I'm simply using the built-in admin functionality to add a user. Nothing fancy - just the built in auth module and the user form that is automatically created in admin.

---

**More Edit**

I required some custom field so I've used a custom class:

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
    ...
    ...
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should use the [`create_user`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.UserManager.create_user) manager method when creating users.

If you're creating custom forms, subclass one of the  [`UserCreationForm`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.forms.UserCreationForm) or [`UserChangeForm`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.forms.UserChangeForm). If you're creating a custom `ModelAdmin`, then subclass `UserAdmin`. Otherwise you'll have to re-implement the password hashing functionality yourself.

Note that the password will be hashed, not encrypted (i.e. you can't decrypt it).

Comment: but doesn't django admin should do this by default. i.e. to hash password when creating new user? I'm using the default form in admin for creating user

Comment: The Django admin's model forms for the `User` model do the hashing by default. You have replaced these with a subclass of `forms.ModelForm`, and lost that functionality.