# How to handle Django ModelForm for Many-to-Many fields

Tags: python, django

I had to show many to many fields on admin pages of both models that had a many to many relationship and I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2216974/django-modelform-for-many-to-many-fields) approach which worked perfectly.

I had to show a field of `tags` while adding/editing user. The field was added, but I lost the functionality of password hashing. So now, I've to use `UserAdmin` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12423796/why-django-doesnt-save-encrypted-password)

Actually, I'm trying this:

```
class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    form = UserForm
```

which is not working with the [existing form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2216974/django-modelform-for-many-to-many-fields) i.e. the `tags` field is not displayed at all. What I need to change?

Answer (score 1):

Try to create [inlines](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects). Inlines let you show and customize related object in admin panel.